# CSS On Hover - Change Element ID1 to ID2

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, jquery-plugins, css-selectors

I am trying to figure out how to swap elements `#1` to `#2` on hover.

So what I need to achieve is that when I hover over `#1` , it will change into `#2`.

Is it possible at all? CSS or jquery in Wordpress?

I haven't really tried anything other then hours googling, I don't really know where to start.

Comment: It's certainly possible, but not a good idea. `id` attributes are intended to be static. IF you're trying to do this for styling reasons, I'd strongly suggest using CSS only, specifically a `:hover` rule.

Comment: Hey Rory, thanks, do you think Miquel's solution below is good to use?

Comment: Sure, that's one solution, although it's not what I read the intention of your question to be; I had thought you want to dynamically change the `id` of a single element at runtime in order to change it's styling.

Comment: Nope, I think that's actually just what I wanted, when I hover element #1, the element#2 will show up instead.

Comment: In that case Miquel's answer is exactly what you need

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to add a container element

```css
.container #two {
  display: none;
}

.container:hover #two {
  display: block;
}

.container:hover #one {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="one">One</div>
  <div id="two">Two</div>
</div>
```